# How to implement a switcher/viewstack component with slot?

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

I'm trying to implement a 'switcher' or 'viewstack' component in Aurelia, this would be useful for wizards, paged content, and stepping through a list of tasks. This would show a single child component at a time from a number of possible children. I'd like the usage markup to resemble:

```
<my-switcher>
    <one-component></one-component>
    <two-component></two-component>
    <three-component></three-component>
</my-switcher>
```

Now, the obvious alternatives here are:

1. `<compose view-model.bind="currentStep">` and point the currentStep variable to each component at a time.
   (+ves: components are only instantiated when accessed, -ves: needing to know the path for each component, all children need to be valid view-models)
2. Add an `if.bind='active'` within the definition of each component in the `slot`, and just set this `active` member from the `my-switcher` class. (+ves: easier to follow, -ves: components need to be specifically written for use here).
3. Retrieve the children via @children (if this now works reliably?) and add the Element as a child DOM element manually, then call `ViewCompiler.enhance`. (-ves: can't seem to get get @children to work, larger amount of custom code)

Each of these feels a bit contrived a solution. Does anyone have any idea about whether there a cleaner approach that could/should be used instead?

Comment: In my experience, @children works fine. What issues have you had with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine options 2 and 3 while avoiding the negatives (not sure why you can't get @children to work).

**consumer.html**

```
<my-switcher>
    <my-switcher-item>
        <one-component></one-component>
    </my-switcher-item>
    <my-switcher-item>
        <two-component></two-component>
    </my-switcher-item>
    <my-switcher-item>
        <three-component></three-component>
    </my-switcher-item>
</my-switcher>
```

**my-switcher-item.js**

```
export class MySwitcherItem {
    constructor() {
        this.isActive = false;
    }
}
```

**my-switcher-item.html**

```
<template show.bind="isActive">
    <slot></slot>
</template>
```

**my-switcher.js**

```
import {children} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class MySwitcher {
    @children('my-switcher-item') items = [];

    // Here you have access to this.items[index].isActive.

    // You can set this value to true or false from this class
    // and make sure only one item's isActive is true.

    // You could add next() and previous() methods to move between
    // the items, etc.
}
```

Comment: If you're not happy about consumers having to add the <my-switcher-item> elements, you could simply add them automatically in a @processContent function in the MySwitcher class.